# Unix script to copy files (which came in a particular duration) from one server to another server

Tags: unix

I need to secure copy files (only .csv) belonging to May & June 2016 (i.e. last modified between 1st May - 30th June 2016) from one source server to target server.

The source server is like->  `10.87.87.89`
source folder -> `/home/server/source`

The Target server is -> `10.34.69.32`
target folder -> `/home/ftp/destination`

Example Username for TARGET: a_ftp
Example Password for TARGET: a_ftp

I have tried the below command-

`scp /home/server/source/h.xml a_ftp@10.34.69.32://home/ftp/destination`

but its not for taking all files.

Comment: Have you tried `scp -r`?

Comment: Remove an extra `/` in the target path `scp /home/server/source/h.xml a_ftp@10.34.69.32:/home/ftp/destination` ?

Comment: I need all .csv files of that source directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create two reference files in the server's filesystem:

```
$ ssh server@10.87.87.89 touch --date "2016-05-01" /tmp/start.tmp
$ ssh server@10.87.87.89 touch --date "2016-06-30" /tmp/end.tmp
```

Now, it is possible to list only the files created in May/2016 and June/2016:

```
$ ssh server@10.87.87.89 find /home/server/source -type f -newer /tmp/start.tmp -not -newer /tmp/end.tmp
```

And finally, you can use `scp` inside a `for` loop, copying only the needed files between the hosts:

```
for i in `ssh server@10.87.87.89 find /home/server/source -type f -newer /tmp/start.tmp -not -newer /tmp/end.tmp`
do
    scp server@10.87.87.89:$i ftp@10.34.69.32:/home/ftp/destination
done
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: And how to select only the .csv files of the required duration?